# Exe4j for Linux

Tags: java, linux, javafx, exe4j

I am newbie, I wanna  ask if there is something like exe4j for Linux? I want to pack my applcation and the enviroment(java jre) of the application, so that I can double click something like exe on windows to run the application on Linux, sorry my English level is low, I hope you guys could understand what I mean

Comment: As @mipa says you can now make [native installers](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/111-making-native-installable-apps-with-java-9) with the JDK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the official solution https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/jpackage/packaging-overview.html instead.